# Spatialite, GeoPackage & Metadata. Are there any python code available to upload metadata?

Tags: python, metadata, geopackage

First of all I am working with spatialite-gui 1.6.0 and spatialite 4.0 and sqlite 3.7.14.1

I want to upload on spatialite and geopackage xml metadata authomatically using python scripts.

The problem is I haven't found any table with an ISO metadata schema in both cases.

Because of that is not clear how I have to proceed. I had to look for a solution, I think only two options are consistent with those formats:

1) create my own iso metadata table and upload one  xml metadata document for  each row of that table.

2) create one metadata table for each spatial layer.

Do you know if there are a better method available to upload and store XML metadata on spatialite either geopackage?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some more information about your problem, and what you've tried.  Add as much detail about your scenario as possible.

Comment: There are some metadata tests in the GDAL autotest script but not about loading xml http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpkg.py.

Comment: The "different folders" you are referring to - do you mean tables? The metadata part isn't well supported in geopackage (now only an extension), and sqlite has no geospatial standard in and of itself (could be spatialite, mbtiles, geopackage, vector tiles, or something else entirely). Can you try cleaning up your question?